# Sending an array from the javascript to the laravel controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Im trying to send an array from my javascript to my laravel controller but when I dd() I get null.
Javascript :

```
$('#submmit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Calendar/store',
                contentType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(partconValues),
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.error('Error sending partconValues to the controller:', error);
                }
            });
        })
```

Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('Request data:', $request->all());
    $partconValues = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $process = \App\Models\Process::find($request->input('partcon_id'));
    $part = \App\Models\ProductPart::find($request->input('part_id'));
    $product = \App\Models\Product::find($request->input('product_id'));

    $userStartTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i', $request->input("start") . ' ' . $request->input("starttime"));
    $workStart = Carbon::createFromTime(8, 0);
    $workEnd = Carbon::createFromTime(18, 0);

    $task = new \App\Models\Task;
    $task->name = $request->input('TaskName');
    $task->process_id = $partconValues;
    dd($task);
    $task->save();

    $totalDuration = $process->construction_time * $request->input('construction_time');

    if ($totalDuration <= $workStart->diffInMinutes($workEnd)) {
        $data = new \App\Models\Calendar;
        $data->name = $process->name;
        $data->code = $product->code . $part->code . $process->code;
        $data->duration = $totalDuration;
        $data->start = $userStartTime;
        $data->finish = $userStartTime->copy()->addMinutes($totalDuration)->toDateTimeString();
        $data->station_id = $request->input('station_id');
        $data->priority = "1";
        $data->save();

        return redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        $remainingDuration = $totalDuration;

        while ($remainingDuration > 0) {
            $currentDayEndTime = $userStartTime->copy()->setTime(18, 0);
            $currentDayActualEndTime = min($currentDayEndTime, $userStartTime->copy()->addMinutes($remainingDuration));

            $data = new \App\Models\Calendar;
            $data->name = $process->name;
            $data->code = $product->code . $part->code . $process->code;
            $data->duration = $currentDayActualEndTime->diffInMinutes($userStartTime);
            $data->start = $userStartTime;
            $data->finish = $currentDayActualEndTime->toDateTimeString();
            $data->station_id = $request->input('station_id');
            $data->priority = "1";
            $data->save();

            $userStartTime = $data->start->setTime(8, 0)->addDay();
            $workEnd = Carbon::createFromTime(18, 0);

            $remainingDuration -= $data->duration;
        }

        return redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

My Laravel log :

```
[2023-11-25 22:27:35] local.INFO: Request data: {"TaskName":"HI","product_id":"1","construction_time":"12","station_id":"1","starttime":"08:00","start":"11/25/2023","_token":"GhbA5tVuVHKGZPb0YM8w0fL9BrsCdvHnaWRWAUGy"}
```

partconValues is the array Im trying to send.
I console loged the array too and it is showing up currectly.
I think my problem is in reciving the array in the controller I tested few ways but I didnt have any luck. please help me thank you.

Comment: you are return redirect not response how to console.log response if redirect ?

Comment: I tested it and then I changed it now but It was correct

Answer (score 0):

If you use `method: 'POST'`, you need to use `{{ csrf_token() }}`

```
$('#submmit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Calendar/store',
        contentType: 'json',
        data: {
            JSON.stringify(partconValues),
            "_method": 'POST',
            "_token":   '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Error sending partconValues ​​to the controller:', error);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).